# Why does Axios.get give me an [object Object]

Tags: mern

I'm trying to get a JSON object into an array to show on a table, however it gives me the error of: TypeError: this.state.allVersions.map is not a function.

```
componentDidMount()
{
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/myblog/' + this.props.match.params.id).then(res =>
    {
        console.log(res.data);
        this.setState({allVersions: res.data});
        console.log(this.allVersions)
    }).catch((err) =>
    {
        console.log(err);
    })
}
```

Here I'm trying using the endpoint to get a JSON object and on the first console log, it gives me the right data but on the second console log it gives me [object Object].

Also,

```
{console.log("state of all versions: " + this.state.allVersions)}
```

gets me an [object Object] but if i do

```
{console.log(this.state.allVersions)}
```

it gets me the right data? Why is removing the string doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation of string and object would make object be converted to a string, not to a JSON. 
Instead you would want to convert your object to JSON before concatenation.

[image]

so in your code it will look like

```
console.log("state of all versions: " + JSON.stringify(this.state.allVersions))
```